# Journalist moves to the island of his ancestors

Tags: identify-this-movie

I've been trying to find this movie where a journalist moves to an island where his ancestors are from.

I don't remember if he is investigating something.

There's a very great scene, a flashback where we see that his family was cast away, and the family is leaving with their whole house, by which I mean they tied ropes to the house and they are dragging it, it was snowing.

There's also a scene of a murder or attempted murder on a boat.

The last name of the protagonist is weird.

Also **I don't know if I'm confusing things with another movie** (it has been years since I saw it on a bus), but I also remember a celebration, a guy fixed his boat, and the people are celebrating, but they end up destroying the boat.

Comment: When did you see this? Language?

Comment: I don't remember how long ago, could be 8 years, the language is English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The movie in question is: [The Shipping News](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120824/)!

I have just found it today while looking at movies with Kevin Spacey, I didn't remember that Kevin Spacey was in this film. If I had I would have found it way sooner!

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you're right in suspecting that you are conflating two different scripts together. One of the movies is possibly Werner Herzog's [Fitzcarraldo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083946/):

> Fitzcarraldo is an obsessed opera lover who wants to build an opera in the jungle. To accomplish this he first has to make a fortune in the rubber business, and his **cunning plan involves hauling an enormous river boat across a small mountain with aid from the local Indians**.

So it's not a house which is dragged, but a riverboat. I don't remember any snow. As you remember, there is a celebration when the boat is sent off and the boat is eventually destroyed.

The character's last name is actually Fitzgerald, but is nicknamed Fitzcarraldo. The actor's last name is Kinski. I'd say that both of them are weird :)

The movie was released in 1982 and the version I've seen was in German. Here's the [trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F53yUsgVuL0).

Comment: BTW, if this answer is correct, please let us know which bus service plays Herzog masterpieces for its passengers. I'd gladly travel on it just for the experience :)

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, gonna check this movie out though looks great!

Comment: Although, in the shipping news, they also smash up another journalists boat and the female character is called 'Wavey' so quite close on all counts.